# How to get rid of white space underneath of an image and before the next text

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML/CSS and have been practicing.
I have been trying to figure out how to delete the space underneath of an image and before a paragraph.

I have tried a few things:
float:left;
display: block;
vertical-align:text-bottom
decreasing the margin to a negative px

I'm not sure if I am putting them in the wrong place or something is wrong with my code.

Here is my HTML code for the portion I need help with:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: #A4A400;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a {
  color: #A4A400;
}

#recipe {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.comments {
  background-color: #FFFFC8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="recipe">
  <header>
    <div class="image">
      <h1>Grandma's Lemon Meringue Pie</h1>
      <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/09sp/homework/1/pie.jpg" alt="Pie" />
      <p>
        One 9-inch pie<br /> 30 Min - Prep time<br /> 10 Min - Cook time<br /> 40 Min - Total<br /> 8 Servings<br />
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
```

I have tried the above methods but there was no change in the spacing. I tried to decrease the margin significantly to see if it was working (I think I used -20px) and it got rid of the space I wanted but then the image was no longer left aligned.

Comment: `p` has a default margin

Comment: The <p> creates space under the image/above the text.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to set the margin on an image but the image has no margin. The margin is on the p tag that you have below it.

If you add:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to your CSS then you will remove that margin that you don't want.

Don't forget to also close your div where you have opened one with the class of 'image' as that isn't closed in your snippet :)

By setting the margin to 0 on all p's as described above you will affect all p's on your website so be careful. You may be better off being more specific and just set the margin on all p's in div's that have the class "image" (image is also quite generic, maybe be a little more specific with your div naming too).

Personally, I would change your CSS to be something like:

```
.recipe-detail p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And then change your code:

```
<div class="recipe-detail">
    <h1>Grandma's Lemon Meringue Pie</h1>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/09sp/homework/1/pie.jpg" alt="Pie" />
    <p>One 9-inch pie<br /> 30 Min - Prep time<br /> 10 Min - Cook time<br /> 40 Min - Total<br /> 8 Servings<br /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The answer was much simpler than I thought.